# PL/SQL procedure to display the details of the employees from employee table whose designation is ‘manager’

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a relation called employee like this:

```
EMPNO       EMPNAME     DESIGNATION     DATEOFJOIN      SALARY      DEPNO
-----       -------     -----------     ---------       ------      ----
101         Sharon       Manager        01-JAN-00       10000         1
102         Gayathri     Manager        01-JAN-00       10000         1
111         Raj          Salesman       05-JAN-00       5000          1
```

I want to create a procedure to display the details of all the employees from employee table whose designation is ‘manager’.. Can you please help me with this?

I want my output to be like this:

```
EMPNO       EMPNAME       DATEOFJOIN    SALARY      DEPNO
-----       -------       ---------     ------      ----
101         Sharon        01-JAN-00     10000         1
102         Gayathri      01-JAN-00     10000         1
```

Comment: Bit baffled by this statement 'I don't know how to display multiple details at a time.' what do you want your output to look like?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I would like to display all the rows whose designation is 'Manager'.. But I have to do it with the help of procedures

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is very simple but your expected output is a bit unclear.

Mostly, this type of requirement is fulfilled via `refcursor`.

I am showing you the example as follows:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SHOW_ACCT_DETAILS (
  2      P_OUT_CUR OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
  3  ) AS
  4  BEGIN
  5      OPEN P_OUT_CUR FOR SELECT ACC_NR, SUM_, CUST_ID
  6                           FROM ACCOUNT
  7                          WHERE SUM_ > 1000;
  8  END SHOW_ACCT_DETAILS;
  9  /

Procedure created.
```

Now, calling the procedure and printing the desired result.

```
SQL> var cur refcursor;

SQL> exec SHOW_ACCT_DETAILS(:cur);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :cur;

    ACC_NR       SUM_    CUST_ID
---------- ---------- ----------
       500       3400        100
       600       5000        101
       700       5070        102

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a simple query?

```
SELECT EMPNO, EMPNAME, DATEOFJOIN, SALARY, DEPNO
FROM employee
WHERE DESIGNATION = 'Manager';
```

If you want to put this into a stored procedure, you should explain how you want to call the procedure.  Otherwise, a `VIEW` would be fine for encapsulating the logic.